# Is that possible to restrict slide view in one direction in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an android app which implements master/detail flow. To switch between master/details them I'm using `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` because it allows to slide views.

Is that possible to restrict slide view from master to details (allow only back navigation to master from details view)?

Comment: Remove the fragment from the list on swiping back.